# socket.emit() that I use inside the function is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

In my application that I developed with React and node.js, the socket emit in the function is not working for some reason, when we press the button, we need to save the data in the backend and send this data to the other party in real time, in short, there will be a chat part.

**Here you can see the code I wrote in React**

```
  const sendMessage = async () => {
    if (message.trim() !== "") {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/messages/",
          {
            content: message,
            chatId: chatId,
          },
          config
        );
        setMessage("");
        if (data) {
          const newData = {
            ...data,
            createdAt: new Date(),
          };
          socket.emit("new message", { newMessage: newData, room: chatId });
          setResponse((prev) => {
            return {
              ...prev,
              messages: [...prev.messages, newData],
            };
          });
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

Actually, this code was working a few hours ago, but now it stopped working for some reason I can't find.

**and here you can see that I've connected the socket**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io("http://localhost:5000/");
    socket.on("connected", () => {
      return;
    });
    socket.emit("join chat", chatId);
  }, []);
```

I'm in the following situation, I performed a test emit operation in useEffect and it worked, but I can't get it to work in this function

**Here you can see the back end part**

```
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: " http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join chat", (room) => {
    socket.join(room);
  });
  socket.on("new message", ({ newMessage, room }) => {
    socket.to(room).emit("message recieved", newMessage);
  });

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("working on 5000");
});
});
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean though? Does the browser not even send a socket message? (is there even a socket connection?)

Comment: First of all, English is not my mother tongue, please forgive me if I am wrong. There is a socket connection like this, other sockets work but the socket inside this function does not work (inside the async function)

Comment: the listener on the back-end side is not triggered in any way in the new message emit

Comment: But does the browser show the socket emitting if you click the network tab and filter for `ws` (web socket traffic)? Or does that not even happen? If it doesn't, put some console.log statements in your client side code: do you ever make it past `const { data } = ...` or is that await simply waiting forever and the rest of your code never triggers?

Comment: actually I tried many methods about 6 hours ago it was working without any problems and the data value was coming and the emit process was also successful, I can't understand the problem exactly.

Comment: That's why I'm asking you: put some console log statements in there and let us know (by updating your post) whether the function "gets stuck". E.g. does your code even get to `setMessage("");` or does it never make it past the axios await. And if it _does_ get there, what's in `data`? Because if it's an empty string or the number 0 or the `undefined` value or `null`, your `if` statement won't trigger because `if(data)` will be false. Basically: look at that axios request, because there are multiple ways in which _it_ can prevent the rest of your code from even running.

Comment: what I mean is that I tried with debbuger, all functions are working, messages are saved in the database, the data value returns correctly, even the socket was working properly, and yes, I also tried logging to the console after the socket broke, there is no problem visible. All the functions you mentioned here are working except emit

Comment: hink the data probably cause the problem, you may be right, I edited the code a little bit and realized that when I send a string value, the socket on the backend side is triggered when I select a string value from the data and send it (data.id), the socket is triggered in the same way, but when I send it directly as data or data.user (it is an object containing user information), this time the socket is not triggered but I really can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, it was an error due to my carelessness, I was sending a data in base64 format when I sent it and the emit process did not take place because it was overrun, I only increased the size limit on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, it was an error due to my carelessness, I was sending a data in base64 format when I sent it and the emit process did not take place because it was overrun, I only increased the size limit on the server side.